# How to test Controller Filters in Ruby on Rails and Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

We have a large application in Ruby on Rails with many filters.  Some of these filters can be complex.  I am looking for a way to individually test these filters with a unit test.  Right now I test them by testing them through an action that uses them with a functional test.  This just doesn't feel like the right way.
Does anyone have advice or experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

Remember a filter is just a method.
Given this:

```
class SomeController
  before_filter :ensure_awesomeness

  ...
end
```

There's no reason you can't just do this:

```
SomeController.new.ensure_awesomeness
```

and then check that it calls redirect_to or whatever it's supposed to do

Comment: If I try this, I get: `ActionController::Metal#session delegated to @_request.session, but @_request is nil: #<JobsController:0xba4beb4 @_routes=nil, @_action_has_layout=true, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil>`

Answer (score 1):

I have [a post](http://smsohan.blogspot.com/2009/05/unit-test-actioncontroller-filters.html) on unit testing before_filters easily, you may wish to take a look. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can testing with this code:

```
require "test_helper"
describe ApplicationController do

  context 'ensure_manually_set_password' do
    setup do
      class ::TestingController < ApplicationController
        def hello
          render :nothing => true
        end
      end

      NameYourApp::Application.routes.draw do 
        get 'hello', to: 'testing#hello', as: :hello
      end
    end

    after do
        Rails.application.reload_routes!
    end

    teardown do
      Object.send(:remove_const, :TestingController)
    end

    context 'when user is logged in' do
      setup do
        @controller = TestingController.new
      end

      context 'and user has not manually set their password' do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, manually_set_password: false) }
        setup do
                    login_as user
          get :hello
        end

        should 'redirect user to set their password' do
          assert_redirected_to new_password_path(user.password_token)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It's code is original from http://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-a-before-filter,
I changed for Rails 3

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your filters are doing.

This: http://movesonrails.com/journal/2008/1/23/testing-your-application-controller-with-rspec.html

And also learning how to use mocha will get you a long way.

Comment: That is good for testing if the filter is in the list for a given action, but it doesn't test the code of the filter itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Orion I have messed with doing that in a few occurrences.  Also, most of the time filters are private so you have to do a send:

```
SomeController.new.send(:some_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue.

What about filters that perform actions requiring a request.  i.e. using Flash

Example being Authlogic require_user method won't work just by using ApplicationController.new.send(:some_filter).

https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

Anyone have some non-hack ideas on how to test this kind of thing in isolation?  (I'm doing it by creating a extra dummy controller that I only use for testing.)