# How can I test ActionController extensions within Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, actioncontroller

I wrote an extension for ActionController::Base in Rails 3.2. Now I want to test it. But because the gem I created is no application it has neither specific controllers nor routes, so I cannot use "get" or "post" to call any action.
Is there any module which can create generic controllers on the fly (like [acts_as_fu](https://github.com/nakajima/acts_as_fu) does with ActiveRecord models)? Or is there any testing pattern I can relate to?

I have found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/how-to-test-controller-filters-in-ruby-on-rails-and-testunit) which explains how to test a before_filter. So far so good although the solutions are to some extend heavy-weight or unclean.

Edit: In particular I want to test an around_filter (if it works and if it redirects correctly) which is created by my extension.

I'm looking forward to your answers.
Thanks and kind regards.